# rails_admin can't get auth working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails_admin gem for my website.
After installing it, and going localhost:3000/admin, anyone can access the admin page, and I want to stop that.

Tutorial I used: http://amrithaprasad.com/2012/09/19/getting-started-with-rails_admin.html

First I'd like to use no gems if its possible, and after browsing I've found this solution in file config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    ADMIN_EMAILS= ['youremail@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
    config.current_user_method { current_user } # auto-generated
    config.authenticate_with {} # leave it to authorize
    config.authorize_with do
        is_admin= ADMIN_EMAILS.include?(current_user.email) 
            if current_user
                redirect_to main_app.new_user_session_url unless is_admin 
            end
    end
```

the issue I'm having here, is that I can't even start a rails server, I mean when I type `rails server` I get some wall of text errors, which is happening only when I type something into this file/writing this code.

This is the entire error I get in terminal :

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load': /home/milos/RubyTest/work/thomas/projectsignal/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/milos/RubyTest/work/thomas/projectsignal/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
        from /home/milos/RubyTest/work/thomas/projectsignal/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/milos/RubyTest/work/thomas/projectsignal/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/milos/RubyTest/work/thomas/projectsignal/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from /home/milos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Can you post at least some part of that `wall of text errors`.

Comment: posted in main question.

Answer (score 1):

`syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)` error clearly states that its expecting `end` keyword.

**Add an `end` at the bottom of your initializer file as you are missing it.**

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    ADMIN_EMAILS= ['youremail@email.com', 'email2@email.com']
    config.current_user_method { current_user } # auto-generated
    config.authenticate_with {} # leave it to authorize
    config.authorize_with do
        is_admin= ADMIN_EMAILS.include?(current_user.email) 
            if current_user
                redirect_to main_app.new_user_session_url unless is_admin 
            end
    end
end  ## Add this
```

Comment: now error is in this line of code:

 if current_user
            redirect_to main_app.new_user_session_url unless is_admin

Comment: That means you don't have a route as `new_user_session_url`. Run `rake routes` and see the list of available routes. If you share the output of `rake routes` then I'll point you in right direction.

Comment: Posted result as a new answer.^^

Comment: Don't post it in the answer. Remove it from there and add it to the question. Which is the route for signing in the application? I don't see any route for sign_in?

Comment: Well according to the tutorial, there shouldt be any. Quote : "Now if you go to localhost:3000/admin, it should prompt you to sign in. If you log in or are logged in already with your admin credentials, you should be good to go. Otherwise you will just get redirected to the home page."
And admin credentials are the ones in the first post > "ADMIN_EMAILS= ['youremail@email.com', 'email2@email.com']"

Comment: This is one of solutions i liked. https://gist.github.com/grosser/1278355

Can we modify my error to use emails i provided in the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i get after i type `rake routes`

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                        Controller#Action
      rails_admin        /admin                                             RailsAdmin::Engine
   category_signs GET    (/:locale)/categories/:category_id/signs(.:format) signs#index {:locale=>/en|sr/}
       categories GET    (/:locale)/categories(.:format)                    categories#index {:locale=>/en|sr/}
             cart GET    (/:locale)/carts/:cart_permalink(.:format)         carts#show {:locale=>/en|sr/}
user_cart_entries GET    (/:locale)/cart/entries(.:format)                  cart_entries#index {:locale=>/en|sr/}
                  POST   (/:locale)/cart/entries(.:format)                  cart_entries#create {:locale=>/en|sr/}
  user_cart_entry PATCH  (/:locale)/cart/entries/:id(.:format)              cart_entries#update {:locale=>/en|sr/}
                  PUT    (/:locale)/cart/entries/:id(.:format)              cart_entries#update {:locale=>/en|sr/}
                  DELETE (/:locale)/cart/entries/:id(.:format)              cart_entries#destroy {:locale=>/en|sr/}
        user_cart GET    (/:locale)/cart(.:format)                          carts#show {:locale=>/en|sr/}
edit_current_user GET    (/:locale)/profile/edit(.:format)                  users#edit {:locale=>/en|sr/}
     current_user GET    (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                       users#show {:locale=>/en|sr/}
                  PATCH  (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                       users#update {:locale=>/en|sr/}
                  PUT    (/:locale)/profile(.:format)                       users#update {:locale=>/en|sr/}
             sign GET    (/:locale)/signs/:id(.:format)                     signs#show {:locale=>/en|sr/}
             page GET    (/:locale)/pages/:permalink(.:format)              pages#show {:locale=>/en|sr/}
                  GET    /:locale(.:format)                                 pages#index
             root GET    /                                                  pages#index

Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
    dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
        index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
          new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
       export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
  bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET         /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
  bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
         show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
         edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
       delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
 history_show GET         /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
  show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```